# Problem with Google App Engine Channel API (Python/Django)

Tags: javascript, django, google-app-engine, push, channel

Hey, everybody.  I'm trying to use the App Engine Channel API (documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html)) to enable push updates for my application.  However, I'm running into some problems setting up the mechanism for initializing a communication channel.

The problem is that, when I load the page in question, I get debug prints for the onError and onClose handlers, but I don't get a debug print for the onOpen handler.  Nothing else happens.  Below is the javascript console output using Google Chrome Developer Tools:

> Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html. .....  jsapi:-1
>
> onError .....   443088:88
>
> onClose .....   443088:80

And here is the relevant section of (mostly) javascript code from my Django template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onOpen = function() {
   console.debug('onOpen');

   var xhrArgs = {
      url: '/channel/connect/',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      postData: dojo.toJson({ 'channel_token': '{{ channel_token }}' }),
      handleAs: 'text',
      load: function(response) {
         alert('success');
      },
      error: function(error) {
         alert('failure: ' + error);
      }
   };
   var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
 };
 
 onClose = function() {
  console.debug('onClose');
 };
 
 onMessage = function(msg) {
  console.debug('onMessage');
 };
 
 onError = function() {
  console.debug('onError');
 };

 openChannel = function() {
  var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{  channel_token }}');
  var handler = {
   'onopen': onOpen,
   'onclose': onClose,
   'onmessage': onMessage,
   'onerror': onError
  };
  var socket = channel.open(handler);
  socket.onopen = onOpen;
  socket.onmessage = onMessage;
 };
 
 setTimeout(openChannel, 100);
 </script>
```

If I understand this correctly, then the server-side code isn't relevant at this point, since onOpen doesn't appear to even be called yet.  I know I must be missing something simple, but if anybody could help out with this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you're using an unitialized channel token. The server needs to call channel.create_channel to retrieve a token for this client, that you'll then pass to the Channel object's constructor.